# Encrypt and decrypt a Room database using AndroidX biometric library

Tags: android, android-room, androidx, password-encryption, android-biometric

I have few questions in my mind. Could you please give me a generic answer or a document links related to these questions.

1. How to encrypt and decrypt Room database of my android application using Fingerprint(Android biometric library).
2. Once encrypted using biometric API, what will happen if the user changes Biometric key/ fingerprint? Will I be able to decrypt my data again?

Comment: answer to 2: No, If the user changes their biometric key or fingerprint, you won't be able to decrypt your data again.